# Can a wmic processes table (within the command prompt window) be sorted by a value?

Tags: sorting, process, cmd, wmic, tasklist

I've been exploring various options, such as the `/format` flag, however it appears that sorting is only possible in XML or HTML output. I would like to sort within command prompt itself. It seems that even [TaskList](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx) cannot do this (and I would prefer to use wmic since it seems to perform faster).

An example of a command to run would be `wmic process get name,processid,workingsetsize`. Processes appear to be sorted by processid, but it would make much more sense (in my use case, at least) to sort by name or memory usage (`workingsetsize`).

As requested, here's an example wmic process table output:

```
Name                          ProcessId  WorkingSetSize
System Idle Process           0          20480
System                        4          765952
smss.exe                      384        393216
csrss.exe                     500        2850816
wininit.exe                   596        774144
csrss.exe                     612        6230016
winlogon.exe                  672        2023424
services.exe                  696        7192576
lsass.exe                     704        9814016
svchost.exe                   820        5287936
svchost.exe                   872        7454720
atiesrxx.exe                  936        1028096
```

Obviously, process lists can get very long, so I've cut it off there.

Comment: Put a wmic output example to your question.

Comment: @Endoro I added one. However, as I mentioned, anyone can run `wmic process get name,processid,workingsetsize` and see exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: You can sort this on the command line with `sed` from the GNUWin Project.

Comment: @Endoro While that may be a valid solution in some cases, my goal is to provide a simple process killer for coworkers, both current and future. Relying on an external tool isn't something I want to do.

Comment: You can also do this with a batch or VB script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims==" %%i IN ('set $ 2^>nul') DO SET "%%i="
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('wmic process get Name^, ProcessId^, WorkingSetSize ') DO (
 IF DEFINED $0 (
  SET wss=%%i
  CALL SET wss=0000000000000000000%%wss:~60%%
  CALL SET wss=%%wss: =%%
  CALL SET wss=$%%wss:~-20%%
  CALL SET %%wss%%=%%i
 ) ELSE (SET $0=%%i)
)

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%i IN ('set $') DO ECHO(%%j
```

This should do your sort.

The sticking points are: the `WMIC` command requires commas between fieldnames. These need to be escaped in the `for/f`

All environment variables starting "$" are first deleted, then each line of `WMIC` is processed. The first line (the header) is saved in `$0` then each line is saved in `$size`

The trick here is that SIZE in the listing is not only left-justified by space-padded, hence the string of zeroes is first prefixed to the contents of the workingsetsize column which probably actually begins in column 62 - but column 61 is a space. "60" is used since the substring facility counts from column 0, not column 1.
Then each space is replaced by [nothing], stripping out the trailing spaces (also conveniently, the space from col 61)
The last 20 characters from the resultant string form a leading-zero-filled version of the workingsetsize column.
prepend a $ to tha, and set the resultant variable to the contents of the line that generated it

Finally, listing the contents of the `$` variables produces the required list in the required order.

Note that the claims that the `WMIC` process output described is in order whatever is erroneous. Closer examination would reveal that it is not in order of ProcessID - either alphabetically (since that column is also left-justified) or alphabetically.

---

OK - revised version, should auto-adjust to width of process-name column:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims==" %%i IN ('set $ 2^>nul') DO SET "%%i="
SET /A COUNT=0
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('wmic process get Name^, ProcessId^, WorkingSetSize ') DO (
 IF DEFINED $0 (
  SET wss=%%i
  CALL %%lopcmd%%
  CALL SET wss2=%%wss2: =%%
  SET /A COUNT+=1
  CALL SET wss=$%%wss2:~-20%%%%COUNT%%
  CALL SET %%wss%%=%%i
 ) ELSE (SET $0=%%i&set/a wsscol=0&CALL :findcol&SET $0=%%i)
)
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%i IN ('set $') DO ECHO(%%j
GOTO :eof

:findcol
IF "%$0:~0,1%"=="W" SET lopcmd=CALL SET wss2=0000000000000000000%%wss:~%wsscol%%%&GOTO :eof
SET $0=%$0:~1%
SET /a wsscol+=1
GOTO findcol
```

No substantial changes - just calculate the width required by locating the "W" in the header and establishing an appropriate command to set the variable ready for processing...and which has to executed using the `CALL %%var%%` method...

---

Minor edit: introducing COUNT to distinguish between lines with identical workingsetsizes. `Count` is simply extends the variable-name used for sorting and makes the name unique.

Comment: On my Win 8 32 bit machine it prints a header line and that is all.  If I add an `echo %%i` it prints the values so the manipulation code isn't operating correctly.

Comment: I believe some code is missing, as the last `ECHO(` statement does not have a closing `)`. This would explain why @foxidrive cannot make it work. Let me know when you update your code.

Comment: @EpicCyndaquil - not the case. `Echo(` is one of many forms of `Echo` which have been found to work - for instance `Echo(%emptyvariable%` produces an empty line whereas `Echo %emptyvariable%` or `Echo.%emptyvariable%` for instance produce an ECHO-status report (ECHO is on/off)

Comment: @foxidrive Works perfectly happily on my W7/64 machine. I don't have access to a W8 machine - but I'm a little disappointed. I'm well aware you have the skills and experience to locate the problem...

Comment: Thank you for the additional knowledge. However, your code produces an empty table for me. (I'm on Win8 x64.) Turning echo off does show that the processes are there, but apparently your sort is excluding them somehow?

Comment: The problem is that the column where the memory figures starts is 47 on my machine and I suspect it may be dynamic where the executable names are very long.  If I change the 60 to 47 then it works just fine.  I confirm the dynamic column as my XP VM has that column in # 33.

Comment: @foxidrive Yes - good one. I have `setiathome_6.10_windows_intelx86__cuda_fermi.exe` - looks like a case of "find the last parameter on the line" is needed - that'll be just a jiffy...

Comment: Your code is a tad complicated and I don't quite understand it, but it does output properly. I'll study it for a while and see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Is this any use to you?  It works in Win 8 to provide a list of processes sorted by memory usage.

```
tasklist /nh |sort /+65
```

Comment: Very interesting! The fact that it can be run remotely is great (and necessary) too. I wish it could show CPU usage too, though, and perhaps have headers as well.

Comment: Take out the /nh and you'll have a footer with the headers. :)  No CPU usage from it I'm afraid.

Comment: That footer is a little funny. Is there any way to add a row of `=` above it so it looks more even?

Answer (score 1):

This might work on the command line (depends on Windows version, without any warranty!):

```
(for /f "delims=" %i in ('wmic process get Name^, ProcessId^, WorkingSetSize ') do @set "wss=%i" &call set "wss=%wss:~0,35%%wss:~-12%"&call echo(%wss%) | more +1 | sort /+35
```

Comment: In Win 8 at least the sorted data is not padded with leading zeros and so doesn't sort properly by size.

Comment: @foxidrive - spaces are also sufficient. In the example here I use only spaces, not leading zeros.

Comment: I don't know what you see, @Endoro, but the output was not sorted by filesize in Win 8.  It was not padded with spaces either.  I forgot to mention that the Wmic command returned an error too.

Comment: OK, thank you. I have no access to Win 8  and after all I never use `wmic`.  :)

Comment: @foxidrive - if you want to see what I see simply use this code and the `wmic`  output posted by the OP and stored in a file.

Comment: Your code doesn't work in XP either.  Invalid GET Expression. and doesn't sort by size.

Comment: I used the code Peter posted, I don't know why there are carets. Escaping commas is not a requirement of cmd. But his answer is accepted :)  Does his code work?

Comment: It does, @Endoro, and yours does too when I remove all the code after the DO and replace it with `DO @echo %i)`.  Yours also works with a file with the text in, as you suggested.  Peter's latest code does the job though.

Comment: I think, this belongs to `wmic`'s  unicode "bug": uncounted number of trailing `CR`'s.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question and this works just fine for me on Windows 10:

```
wmic process list  get name, version |sort
or
wmic process list status |sort
or
wmic process list io |sort
```

Expounding upon Foxidrive's answer, this works with tasklist also:

```
tasklist /nh | sort
```

and no need for the /+65 (thanks for that info foxidrive)

"tasklist" on Windows 10 will do this also:

```
tasklist /nh /fo table
or
tasklist /fo list
or
tasklist /nh |sort
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Peter's technique here but returned the data in CSV format, which is easier to parse for a batch file in "PID, WorkingSetSize, Name" format sorted on the size column.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims==" %%i IN ('set $ 2^>nul') DO SET "%%i="
FOR /f "skip=2 tokens=2-4 delims=," %%a IN ('cmd /c "wmic process get Name, ProcessId, WorkingSetSize /format:csv" ') DO (

  SET wss=0000000000000000000%%c
  CALL SET $%%wss:~-20%%=%%b,%%c,%%a

)

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%i IN ('set $') DO ECHO(%%j
pause
```

Comment: No offense, but that output is pretty ugly. You did indeed sort the data though, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

If PowerShell is an option for you then the following should work:

`PS C:\> Get-CimInstance -query "select * from win32_process" | Sort-Object -Property Name | Format-Table -Property Name, ProcessId, WorkingSetSize`