# Is there any way to remove the entries with same process names?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wmic, taskmanager

I'm trying to get the top 10 memory consuming processes and I am using the code provided as an answer in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487895/find-top-10-processes-with-wmic-command). It works fine except that I don't want multiple entries of processes consuming different memory size and I was unable to sort it because it's memory consumption is different.
The code is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%a in ('wmic process get name^,workingsetsize') do (
set "size=         %%b"
echo !size:~-10!:%%a
)) > wmicc.txt
set i=0
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('sort /R wmicc.txt') do (
echo %%a
set /A i+=1
if !i! equ 25 goto :end
)
:end
```

Can I get the output as:

```
96931840:iexplore.exe
82161664:explorer.exe
42319872:svchost.exe
31469568:dwm.exe
25690112:SearchIndexer.exe
17002496:taskhostex.exe
11007590:VCExpress.exe
8033894:avp.exe
7190528 :Skype.exe
7000416 :SkypeBrowserHost.exe
```

Instead of the output from existing code:

```
96931840:iexplore.exe
82161664:explorer.exe
42319872:svchost.exe
33656832:svchost.exe
31469568:dwm.exe
26943488:iexplore.exe
25690112:SearchIndexer.exe
18550784:svchost.exe
17002496:taskhostex.exe
16343040:svchost.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set num=25

set /A skip=-num
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%a in ('wmic process get name^,workingsetsize') do (
   set "size=         %%b"
   set "size=!size:~-10!"
   if not defined proc[%%a] (
      set "proc[%%a]=!size!"
      set "size[!size!:%%a]=1"
      set /A skip+=1
   ) else if %%b gtr !proc[%%a]! (
      set "size[!proc[%%a]!:%%a]="
      set "proc[%%a]=!size!"
      set "size[!size!:%%a]=1"
   )
)

if %skip% lss 1 (set "skip=") else set "skip=skip=%skip%"
for /F "%skip% tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('set size[') do echo %%a
```

Output example:

```
   5517312:NisSrv.exe
   5537792:HD-LogRotatorService.exe
   5939200:spoolsv.exe
   6062080:WUDFHost.exe
   6168576:igfxpers.exe
   6279168:conhost.exe
   6369280:wmpnetwk.exe
   6533120:hkcmd.exe
   6692864:igfxtray.exe
   8073216:notepad.exe
   8077312:WMIC.exe
   8105984:taskhost.exe
   9306112:lsass.exe
  11157504:winlogon.exe
  11767808:taskhostex.exe
  13402112:SkyDrive.exe
  16629760:TabTip.exe
  17121280:SearchIndexer.exe
  26120192:HD-Agent.exe
  32325632:csrss.exe
  36429824:svchost.exe
  43114496:dwm.exe
 101998592:explorer.exe
 110260224:MsMpEng.exe
 114425856:chrome.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims==" %%a in ('set @ 2^>nul') do set "%%a="

(for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%a in ('wmic process get name^,workingsetsize') do (
set "size=         %%b"
echo !size:~-10!:%%a
)) > wmicc.txt
set i=0
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('sort /R wmicc.txt') do (
 for /f "tokens=1*" %%p in ("%%a") do (
  rem the following line doesn't work
  rem if not defined "@%%q"
  rem the preceding line doesn't work
  SET "flag="
  FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%v IN ('set @%%q 2^>nul') DO IF /i "%%v"=="@%%q" SET "flag=Y"
  IF NOT DEFINED flag (
   set "@%%q=Y"
   echo %%a
   set /A i+=1
   if !i! equ 25 goto :end
  )
 )
)
:end
```

This tokenises the entire line as read into `%%p,q` so `%%q` contains the process-name. It then checks whether the variable `@processname` is defined and if it is not, generates the report-line and sets `@processname` so that the first mention will be the last as that variable is now defined.

The first line is designed to set any existing `@*` variables to *empty*; the `2^>nul` suppresses error messages should no `@*` variables exist and the caret escapes the `>` to tell `cmd` that the `>` is part of the command to be executed, not of the `for`.

[later]

It appears that the `if defined "varname"` that I invented doesn't actually work, although it appeared to work when I tested it. I've replaced that instruction with code that does work and marked it out.

Comment: @San852 are you sure, you just want to disregard the multiples rather than adding their size?

Comment: @Stephan yes, I'm sure. I'm more interested in the process names and the added size isn't too important for me.

Comment: The data you've posted in your question shows whitespace separating the number and name. The data you've posted in your image shows colons. If you have colons in your data as shown, then change `for /f "tokens=1*" %%p` to `for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%p`

Comment: @Magoo Yes, sorry I've shown wrong output in the code(corrected now), I'm adding colon in this line, it's there in the above code .`echo !size:~-10!:%%a` . Unfortunately I'm still getting multiple entries for both with colon and without, anything I'm missing?

Comment: Fixed. Oh - btw: it's always best to copy-and-paste both code and data. I believe that in your reported data you should have the space on the short first column at the beginning, not before the colon.

Comment: Thank you, I'll make sure I post the exact output and code henceforth. But this code just gives out only one entry/process name.